# If previous element in int array == bool variable

Tags: c#, int, boolean

New to C# for the most part.  I am creating a bowling score application

I am writing an if statement to determine if the *previous element* from my `int[] array` (which has the `bool` variable set to true from earlier code) is `true`.

I know that you *can't have* an `int == bool`, but I am not sure how I write out this statement.

```
public static bool isStrike = false; //Global Declaration

Console.WriteLine("..."); 

rollOne = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (...) {
    isStrike = true;
}

if (array[int - 1] == isStrike) 
{
...
}
```

I want the statement to validate that the *previous element* in the array has the `isStrike bool` set to `true`.

Comment: Use a `List` rather than an array. Then ask the `List` for its last entry.

Comment: I assume using OOP is off the table?

Comment: What is this? `array[int - 1]`. int is a keyword and can't be used there like an identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, we map `int` to `bool` as :

```
 integer_value == 0  => corresponds to false
 integer_value != 0  => corresponds to true
```

which we can put as

```
 bool value = integer_value != 0
```

In your case, if `rollOne` is the index you want to check (if value at `array[rollOne - 1]` is such that...)

```
 public static bool isStrike = false; //Global Declaration

 ...

 isStrike = true;

 ...

 //TODO: validate user input. What if user write "Bla-Bla-Bla"?
 rollOne = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

 // Do not forget to validate user input: wahat if rollOne = -1234? rollOne = 1234567890? 
 if ((rollOne > 0 && rollOne < array.Length) && 
     ((array[rollOne - 1] != 0) == isStrike)) {
   // rollOne is a valid index (not, say, -1234)
   // array[rollOne - 1] when treated as bool equals to isStrike
 }
 else 
 {
   // either index is wrong or array[rollOne - 1] doesn't correspond to isStrike
 }
```

You should use a bit different code if you want to check if

1. `isStrike` is `true`
2. `array[rollOne - 1]` corresponds to `true` as well:

Code:

```
...

if ((isStrike) && 
    (rollOne > 0 && rollOne < array.Length) && 
    (array[rollOne - 1] != 0)) {
   // isStrike is true 
   // rollOne is a valid index (not, say, -1234)
   // array[rollOne - 1] when treated as bool equals to isStrike (true)
 }
```

Comment: though not required, I'd put some `()` around the boolean expression in the assignment for readability.

Comment: `rollOne > 0` should be `rollOne >= 1` to make it more readable. and `rollOne < array.Length` should be `rollOne <= array.Length` to allow the last index to be selected. maybe?

Comment: @FalcoGer: Thank you! `rollOne >= 1` can well appear *more readable* then `rollOne > 0`. However, I doubt if `rollOne <= array.Length` is the right choice based on the information provided. Often, we check condition for pervious item and do / do not something with current one (e.g. "if pervious corresponds to `true`, add `1` to current"). In this case `rollOne <= array.Length` will be the wrong  code.

Answer (score 1):

Turn your integer into a boolean with some mapping.
The usual way to do this is to have 0: false, non 0: true:

```
if ((intArray[i - 1] != 0) == boolVar)
{...}
```

`(intArray[i - 1] != 0)` evaluates into a boolean expression, which you can compare to.

You should however **always** check user input. In case you did do that and removed the check for the MVCE, then good job.

Checking user input:

```
String strInput = Console.ReadLine();
int input = int.MinValue;
// try to parse the string into an integer, returns false if failed. otherwise true.
// if successfull input will be assigned the parsed value by reference.
// int.Parse() will return an integer directly, and will throw an exception on error. this should be used with strings that should always be integers
// try parse should be used where users can enter dumb things.
if (int.TryParse(strInput, out input))
{
    if (input >= 1 /*1 because you subtract 1 in your code. otherwise 0*/ && input <= intArray.Length)
    {...}
    else
    {/*bad value, out of bounds.*/}
}
else
{/*error message*/}
```

Comment: `intArray[i - 1] == (boolVar ? 1 : 0)` is OK if we sure that *all items* of `intArray` are either `0` or `1`; when `intArray[i - 1] != 0` is a typical `int` to `bool` map. User input *validation* is very good practice; may I ask you provide an example of it: `int.TryParse` followed by *borders check* since you've **highlighted** the topic?

Comment: I suggest to put `int.TryParse` into `while` (keep asking user while (s)he provides incorrect input); +1

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i think that goes too far. the question was how to compare an integer to a boolean, not how to ask the user for input.